# Datatables deferRender not being triggered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to improve the load time performance for this datatable. So far it loads just over 700 records and it's already really slow. Am I using deferRender correctly in this instance? It doesn't seem to change or improve anything. I'm thinking it might be the loadJSON function hindering it.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#log_table').dataTable( {
        "deferRender": true,
        "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {

        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
        ]
    } );
} );

function loadJSON(data){
    console.log(data);
    var t = $('#log_table').DataTable();
    t.clear();
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(json, function(key,value) {
        t.row.add( [
            value.uuid,
            value.date,
            value.username,
            value.loggedTable,
            value.action_performed,
            value.queryString
        ] ).draw();
    });
}

$("#audit_trail_menu").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: './inc/AuditTrailScripts.php?argument=loadAllRecords',
        success: function(data) {
            loadJSON(data);

        }
    })
});
```

PHP

```
if(!empty($_GET["argument"])){
    /*
     * loadAllRecords
     * Fetch all records to load into the datatable
     * table to fetch from - media
     */
    if ($_GET['argument']=='loadAllRecords'){
        $json= fetchAll();
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe You write a server script, which returns json with only piece of data.It may render next data bundle after user interaction eg. clicking next on Datatable delegating proper event.

To achieve this, you may send a parameter to PHP script, for example number of bundle.